# Execution commands for a Trello-like program on GitHub

Tags: python, reactjs, web-applications, flask-sqlalchemy, clone

**Background**

I'm trying to execute the Trello-like program on GitHub: https://github.com/delitamakanda/treelo.

The README.md file on the GitHub was not written detailed, 
so I would appreciate it if you could explain it to me to run it on the browser.

**Problem**

It has failed to do it with the following command and environment settings.

Error Message on http://127.0.0.1:5000/

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. 
If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

Execution Command

```sh
$ FLASK_APP=manage.py FLASK_DEBUG=true flask run
```

Terminal Response

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Nov/2019 11:43:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Nov/2019 11:43:03] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

**What I did**

On the treelo-master folder, I have executed the following command on Terminal and it was succeeded to create a virtual environment with requirements.txt.

```sh
$ python3 -m venv env
$ source env/bin/activate
 pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Response

```
Installing collected packages: SQLAlchemy, MarkupSafe, Mako, python-editor, 
six, python-dateutil, alembic, aniso8601, click, Jinja2, itsdangerous, 
Werkzeug, Flask, Flask-Cors, Flask-SQLAlchemy, Flask-Migrate, pytz, 
Flask-RESTful, Flask-Script
 Running setup.py install for SQLAlchemy ... done
 Running setup.py install for MarkupSafe ... done
 Running setup.py install for Mako ... done
 Running setup.py install for python-editor ... done
 Running setup.py install for alembic ... done
 Running setup.py install for itsdangerous ... done
 Running setup.py install for Flask-Script ... done
Successfully installed Flask-1.0 Flask-Cors-3.0.4 Flask-Migrate-2.1.1 Flask-RESTful-0.3.6 
Flask-SQLAlchemy-2.3.2 Flask-Script-2.0.6 Jinja2-2.10.1 Mako-1.0.7 MarkupSafe-1.0 
SQLAlchemy-1.3.0 Werkzeug-0.15.3 alembic-0.9.9 aniso8601-3.0.0 click-6.7 
itsdangerous-0.24 python-dateutil-2.7.3 python-editor-1.0.3 pytz-2018.4 six-1.11.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above project is basically telling you to open two terminal instances. In one of them, you have to run

```
npm install
npm start
```

This will spin up your frontend app in the default webpack port.

The Flask setup requires you to run the `virtualenv`. If you don't have it please install it using the link here - https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation/

After doing so you have to execute the commands in the API as they are given in the README.md

```
virtualenv venv

source venv/bin/activate

## exit venv
exit venv

# run debug server
python manage.py server

# create db
python manage.py db init

# scan all new tables and columns
python manage.py db migrate -m "initial migration"

# apply migrations
python manage.py db upgrade
```

This will spin up your Flask Server successfully at http://localhost:5000/api. I think the last steps you have already done so your server should be up and running if everything went correctly.